# Read Sections of the File in PHP for Creating Labels

Tags: php

I have a file which extract data from MYSQL database to create labels. I have add a string "BREAK" where labels end. My data file looks like this.

```
--------- Start File -------

BREAK
Order: 10000
NAME: XYZ
Phone: XXX-XXX-XXX

6 x ABC
6 x Main ST
6 x CITY
6 x STATE
6 x COUNTRY

BREAK
Order: 10001
NAME: XYZ1
Phone: XXX-XXX-XXX

BMC
MJ ST
CITY
STATE
COUNTRY

BREAK
Order: 10002
NAME: XYZ2
Phone: XXX-XXX-XXX

BMC
MJ ST
CITY
STATE
COUNTRY

......more orders..

--------- End File -------
```

In addition to reading 3  or more blocks and printing them separate, for the first block which is  "6 x", I would like to remove "6 x" from the block and instead store 6 as a value in a variable to be used with lpr/print command on unix for printing 6 copies. This is not a major issue, I can probably figure it out later but reading these blocks in php and creating 3 or more files from them is my requirement.

Comment: Can you just add sample output of what you want ...

Comment: I need this information sliced into files between BREAK tags however BREAK is not at the end so for the last order it should read until end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

this little script parses your order into a multidimensional array (see output below).
from this array you can produce any other format, like inserting it into a database, write it into other files or whatever.

**parser**

```
$orders = explode("BREAK", $fileContents);
array_shift($orders); // only required if a "BREAK" is before the first order
$ordersData = array();
foreach($orders as $order) {

    if (preg_match("/Order: ([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+NAME: ([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+Phone: ([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+(.+)/si", $order, $regs)) {

        $items = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $regs[4], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach ($items as &$item) {

            if (preg_match("/(\d+) *?x *?(.+)/", $item, $regs2)) {

                $item = array(
                    'count' => $regs2[1],
                    'item' => $regs2[2]
                );
            } else {

                $item = array(
                    'count' => 1,
                    'item' => $item
                );
            }
        }

        $orderData = array(
            'order_no' => $regs[1],
            'name' => $regs[2],
            'phone' => $regs[3],
            'items' => $items
        );

        $ordersData[] = $orderData;
    }
}
```

**output format**

```
$ordersData = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_no] => 10000
            [name] => XYZ
            [phone] => XXX-XXX-XXX
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 6
                            [item] =>  ABC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 6
                            [item] =>  Main ST
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 6
                            [item] =>  CITY
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 6
                            [item] =>  STATE
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 6
                            [item] =>  COUNTRY
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_no] => 10001
            [name] => XYZ1
            [phone] => XXX-XXX-XXX
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => BMC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => MJ ST
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => CITY
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => STATE
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => COUNTRY
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_no] => 10002
            [name] => XYZ2
            [phone] => XXX-XXX-XXX
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => BMC
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => MJ ST
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => CITY
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => STATE
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 1
                            [item] => COUNTRY
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the script but how can I print the output. I don't see the output what you have shown in the example.

Comment: Great.. it is getting data as I expected.. thanks sooooooo much.. Now how do I create files for each array so that I can send them to printer. For the same example, I should have 3 files for each array and only the relevant information like address header and items underneath it.